# Image widget not rebuilding on setState

Tags: flutter, dart, search

I am trying to implement search in my flutter app. it's something like an e commerce app with images and name of each product. The search is supposed to filter out products from a list using the entered query. Well it is working fine but only the text widgets gets rebuilt. The images are not moving just the text; more like saying that the image widget is not rebuilding even when it is in a stateful widget. I observed that the `GetImg()` widget which is the custom widget i built for fetching images is actually only called when there is something new to be built. E.g. If I had 10 matches already on my screen and I type in more characters into the search input, lesser matching results shows up but the `GetImg()` widget isn't rebuilt which makes the already built images to stay at their positions even when they are supposed to rebuild and change. The `GetImg()` widget only builds when I backspace and more matches shows up. Note that it did not actually build the already present images but the new ones. I just hope my issue is understood.

Here is my search function:

```
List filterProducts(String text, List items) {
    List searchedList = items
        .where((item) =>
            item.title
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(text.trim().toLowerCase()) ||
            item.price
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(text.trim().toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
    return searchedList;
}
```

This is how I am looping them out:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          ),
          child: Hero(
            tag: widget.product.id,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              child: GetImage(widget.product.images[0]), // GetImage is the widget class I fetch images with; and it does not rebuild
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        formatPrice(widget.product.price),
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ) // the Text widget rebuilds adequately
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

GetImage file (in case if necessary):

```
class GetImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String productName;

  GetImage(this.productName);

  @override
  _GetImageState createState() => _GetImageState();
}

class _GetImageState extends State<GetImage> {
  StorageReference photoRef =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('productImages');
  Uint8List imageFile;

  getImage() {
    if (!requestedIndexes.contains(widget.productName)) {
      int maxSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
      photoRef.child(widget.productName).getData(maxSize).then((data) {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            imageFile = data;
          });
        }
        imageData.putIfAbsent(widget.productName, () {
          return data;
        });
      }).catchError((error) {
        debugPrint(error.toString());
      });
      requestedIndexes.add(widget.productName);
    }
  }

  Image displayImage() {
    dynamic size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    if (imageFile == null) {
      return Image.asset(
        'assets/icons/loader.gif',
        height: size.height,
        width: size.width * 0.5,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    } else {
      return Image.memory(
        imageFile,
        height: size.height,
        width: size.width * 0.5,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (!imageData.containsKey(widget.productName)) {
      getImage();
    } else {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          imageFile = imageData[widget.productName];
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Image build(BuildContext context) {
    return displayImage();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling getImage in initState and it will not update image because it's not calling in build. When you update product name, build function doesn't refer updated product name. This is just the reason. If possible, please call getImage function in build.

Comment: thanks. this helped me figure out the issue. truely, the getImage wasn't running and the imageFile doesn't get updated with the imageData of the current productName. I had to setState in the build